# How to get a shortcut of an exe for the command line in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to run the command line :
"php file.php"
insted of 
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe file.php"

I tried to look on registry editor, without success

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 5):

You can add C:\xampp\php\ to your PATH env variable. Test it out locally by doing this:

```
C:\>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\php
C:\>php file.php
```

In the end, if you want to keep this across multiple cmd sessions, you will need to go into your System dialog in your Control Panel and add it to the Path environment variable there.

Answer (score 0):

You could [doskey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKey) at a command prompt.

```
doskey /?
```

will give you brief help,

```
doskey php=C:\xampp\php\php.exe $*
```

will define a macro so that

```
php file.php
```

will expand to

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe file.php
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a registry key where you can register applications called App Paths.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121(VS.85).aspx